# how to add function (def) to dataset for more then one column ? can anyone help me out pls

Tags: python, function, dataset

```
def total_score(x, y):
    if x >= 35 and y >= 35:
        return 'pass'
    return 'fail'

st['total_score'] = st[['pretest','posttest']].apply(total_score)
```

```
TypeError: total_score() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a function row-by-row:

```
def row_total_score(row):
     if row['pretest] >= 35 and row[posttest] >= 35:
         return 'pass'
     return 'fail'

st['total_score'] = st.apply(row_total_score)
```

You could also write your function as

```
def row_total_score(row):
     if min(row['pretest], row[posttest]) >= 35:
         return 'pass'
     return 'fail'
```

or

```
def row_total_score(row):
     return 'pass' if min(row['pretest], row[posttest]) >= 35 else 'fail'
```